# Identifying entries in java keystore

Tags: java, security, keystore

In my program I need to get key from keypair included in a pkcs12 archive using java. As I don't know keypair alias, I have to iterate through all aliases in keystore. 
Question is, how can I identify keypair? 
I'm using this code to get a key and certificate chain:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream(new File(p12Path)), p12Password);
Enumeration aliases = ks.aliases();
String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
p12Key = ks.getKey(alias, p12Password);
p12Chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
```

I would like to identify entry as keypair or just certificate/chain

```
Entry entry = kspkcs12.getEntry(alias, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [KeyStore.isKeyEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#isKeyEntry-java.lang.String-)

Note the only possible Entry's are a PrivateKeyEntry containing a privatekey and (matching) chain of one or more cert(s), or a TrustedCertEntry containing exactly one cert but never more than one. PKCS12 format doesn't support SecretKeyEntry.

In practice PKCS12 files created by anything *other than Java* will usually have only one PrivateKeyEntry and nothing else, but there is no guarantee.